# CLSI on ubuntu 11.10 / 12.04 (EC2 instance) using chef

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I'm trying to install CLSI on ubuntu 11.10 using chef (see: https://github.com/scribtex/clsi-chef).

I'm trying to get a CLSI server up and running but I'm not able to :( Getting:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[libreadline5-dev]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
libreadline5-dev has no candidate in the apt-cache

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cookbooks/nginx-passenger/recipes/default.rb

 15: package "libreadline5-dev"
 16: package "build-essential"

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cookbooks/nginx-passenger/recipes/default.rb:15:in `from_file'

package("libreadline5-dev") do
  recipe_name "default"
  retry_delay 2
  cookbook_name :"nginx-passenger"
  retries 0
  action :install
  package_name "libreadline5-dev"
end

[Wed, 14 Nov 2012 17:09:45 +0000] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Wed, 14 Nov 2012 17:09:45 +0000] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Wed, 14 Nov 2012 17:09:45 +0000] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[Wed, 14 Nov 2012 17:09:45 +0000] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Package: package[libreadline5-dev] (nginx-passenger::default line 15) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: libreadline5-dev has no candidate in the apt-cache
```

Is anyone able to successfully install it?

I have added nginx-passenger in clsi.json
so the line looks:

> "run_list" : [ "mysql::server", "mysql::client", "nginx-passenger", "clsi" ]

Comment: This looks off-topic to me: would migration to AskUbuntu make sense?

Comment: @JosephWright♦: Already flagged.